# How to loop over a groupby function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, nan

I'm trying to perform an action on grouped data in Pandas. This is a view of that dataset and i want to filter my dataframe as i made in the next lines of code. I want to made that automatically, but i don´t know how to start. Do you recommend a for loop or a function?

`usu[["PONDERA","AGLOMERADO","PP03J","ESTADO","INTENSI"]].head(20)`

`PONDERA  AGLOMERADO  PP03J   ESTADO  INTENSI
0        861    2         NaN        3  NaN
1        861    2         NaN        3  NaN
2        861    2         NaN        3  NaN
3        861    2         NaN        3  NaN
4        861    2         NaN        4  NaN
5        861    2         NaN        4  NaN
6        861    2         NaN        3  NaN
7        861    2         NaN        4  NaN
8        861    2         1.0        1  3.0
9        861    2         NaN        4  NaN
10       861    2         2.0        1  3.0
11       861    2         NaN        3  NaN
12       514    2         2.0        1  2.0
13       503    2         2.0        1  3.0
14       503    2         NaN        3  NaN
15       503    2         2.0        1  3.0
16       919    2         NaN        3  NaN
17       919    2         NaN        3  NaN
18       888    2         2.0        1  2.0
19       888    2         2.0        1  1.0`

````
pob = pob.groupby("AGLOMERADO")["PONDERA"].sum()
pob
pon_oc =usu[["PONDERA","ESTADO"]]
pon_oc = pon_oc["PONDERA"].loc[(usu['ESTADO'] == 1)]
pon_oc["AGLOMERADO"] = usu["AGLOMERADO"]
#pon_oc.info()
pon_oc = pon_oc.groupby("AGLOMERADO").sum()
#Poblacion desocuapada por aglomerados
pon_desoc =usu[["PONDERA","ESTADO"]]
pon_desoc = pon_desoc["PONDERA"].loc[(usu['ESTADO'] == 2)]
pon_desoc["AGLOMERADO"] = usu["AGLOMERADO"]
#pon_oc.info()
pon_desoc = pon_desoc.groupby("AGLOMERADO").sum()
#Poblacion ocupada demandante
pon_ocd =usu[["PONDERA","ESTADO","PP03J"]]
pon_ocd = pon_ocd["PONDERA"].loc[(usu['ESTADO'] == 1) & (usu["PP03J"] ==1)]
pon_ocd["AGLOMERADO"] = usu["AGLOMERADO"]
#pon_oc.info()
pon_ocd =pon_ocd.groupby("AGLOMERADO").sum()
pon_ocd
#Subocupados demandantes
pon_subocd =usu[["PONDERA","ESTADO","PP03J","INTENSI"]]
pon_subocd = pon_subocd["PONDERA"].loc[(usu['ESTADO'] == 1) & (usu["PP03J"] ==1) & (usu["INTENSI"] == 1)]
pon_subocd["AGLOMERADO"] = usu["AGLOMERADO"]
pon_subocd =pon_subocd.groupby("AGLOMERADO").sum()
pon_subocd```
````

Comment: Can you better explain what end result are you expecting.And what operation is to be performed.

Comment: Hi @Shahir Ansari, i want to build a for loop that create the sum of "AGLOMERADO" variable using diferent filter from the other columns.

Comment: how are you deciding the filter just all filters one by one?

Comment: Nowadays it´s my method, but i was trying to do a for loop but i haven´t success. Maybe i should try with a function